# PHP make json_encode DO NOT escape double quotes

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using laravel and I want to seed json in my database. So what I'm doing is json_encode($array). But this puts `"\"`  on every `"` **(double quote)**, which I don't want, how can I generate json from array without putting slashes in fron of every double quote?

This is the array:

```
$fields = [
            [
                'name' => 'image',
                'type' => 'file',
                'view' => 'image',
                'validations' => 'required|image',
                'label' => 'image'
            ]
        ];
```

When I use `json_encode($fields)` it stores it in the db like:

```
"[{\"name\":\"image\",\"type\":\"file\",\"view\":\"image\",\"validations\":\"required|image\",\"label\":\"image\"}]"
```

I don't want those slashes, because I have to use `json_decode()` twice because of them. Also that `$casts` attribute in Laravel decodes them only once.

**FIX**
This is what I tried and it worked

I have this in my model:

```
/**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'fields' => 'array',
        'translatable_fields' => 'array'
    ];
```

So it should decode it automatically.
This is how was I saving it in the database from the seeder:

```
$moduleTemplate = new ModuleTemplate;
        $moduleTemplate->translateOrNew('en')->name = 'Image with text';
        $moduleTemplate->translateOrNew('bg')->name = 'Снимка с тескт';
        $moduleTemplate->view = 'section-1';

        $fields = collect([
            [
                'name' => 'image',
                'type' => 'file',
                'view' => 'image',
                'validations' => 'required|image',
                'label' => 'image'
            ]
        ]);

        $moduleTemplate->fields = $fields->toJson();

        $translatableFields = collect([
            [
                'name' => 'title',
                'type' => 'text',
                'view' => 'input',
                'validations' => 'required|string|max:190',
                'label' => 'title'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'text',
                'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                'view' => 'wysiwyg',
                'validations' => 'required|string',
                'label' => 'text'
            ]   
        ]);

        $moduleTemplate->translatable_fields = $translatableFields->toJson();
        $moduleTemplate->save();
```

And it was putting the slashes everytime
What I did to fix it was simply to remove `->toJson()` from the arrays and it worked

Comment: Without ``\`` your json will not be decoded.

Comment: Actually this is the problem, when I try to decode it WITH the slashes, it returns an error, but when it is without the `\` everything is fine. That's why I am trying to avoid that

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are getting.

Comment: `$fields = [
         [
          'name' => 'image',
          'type' => 'file',
          'view' => 'image',
          'validations' => 'required|image',
          'label' => 'image'
         ]
        ];`
then
`json_encode($fields)`
returns `"[{\"name\":\"image\",\"type\":\"file\",\"view\":\"image\",\"validations\":\"required|image\",\"label\":\"image\"}]"`

Comment: _“When I use json_encode($fields) it returns […]”_ - **it doesn’t:** https://3v4l.org/G8qmE You must be treating your data wrong somehow somewhere after that.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe laravel does it when I try to save it in the database. Am I supossed to change the title of the question now ?

Comment: You left out that you are saving a string to the DB. Most ORMs will escape the string ie json with slashes.

Comment: @nerdlyist My question is starting with that I am trying to save it in the database with laravel

Comment: Sorry my oversight. You do. However ORMs and PHP SQL mechanisms in general escape strings it is for security. When you retrieve this from the DB however it should be unescaped. Can you provide the code to write and read to your DB?

Comment: The `$casts` declaration also seems odd, given that once you `->toJson` both fields, they'd become strings, not arrays.

Comment: Actually I fixed it, you can look at the FIX section in my question :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your quotes format from

```
json_encode('"glossary": {"title": "example glossary"}');
```

to

```
json_encode("'glossary': {'title': 'example glossary'}");
```

**Edit based on your comments**

With

```
$fields = [ [ "name" => "image", 'type' => 'file', 'view' => 'image', 'validations' => 'required|image', 'label' => 'image' ] ];
```

When I do

```
json_encode($fields)
```

It returns me

```
[{"name":"image","type":"file","view":"image","validations":"required|image","label":"image"}]
```

Using Laravel 4.2, not tested with Laravel > 5

You might be doing something wrong with your JSON data

Comment: Upvoted based on the edit.  I get correct results using pure PHP (no laravel, etc) on multiple machines (debian stable, oldstable, ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu 18.04).